# Django, Python: How do I know if users have closed their browser without click logout?

Tags: python, django

Django, Python: How do I know if users have closed their browser without click logout?

Really seriously question, because I need to analyse the user activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it something to not do , but you can do something similar to Gmail (the way that they track if a user is still connected or not) you can do an AJAX request each 10 second or so *(max time that will take a page to be loaded so that you don't mistake changing page to disconnection)* , this Ajax request is like a "i'm still here" when it's received by the view
it reset a timer *( this timer have been initialized for each user from the beginning )* to 0 otherwise if this timer exceed 10 s , you can say that the user "is gone without disconnecting".

you can pull also another way using  comet (reverse Ajax) lcheck [Orbited](http://code.google.com/p/django-orbited/).

by the way disconnecting can me more than one thing : click on a disconnect link, remove session cookies , close page ...

Comment: I think we can all agree this is something not to do.

Answer (score 4):

HTTP is a stateless protocol: you can't know at the server if the user has simply closed their browser without informing you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but you could fire off ajax requests with the user's session info (or some cookie, or any way of identifying the user) every x seconds with javascript and if you haven't received anything from that user in 2*x seconds, then they're likely to have left the page/site.